# Golf Glove Rules

Tags: rules, equipment, golf

Is it legal to wear a golf glove that has some of the "fingers" missing (cut off)?

The idea for doing this comes from reading Hogan's book "Five Lessons". Hogan talks about the muscles that are activated by gripping the club according to his formulation; the pressure points for the left hand would be the last three fingers of the left hand( for right handed swingers here) and the two middle fingers of the right hand. An easy way to maximize this ideal grip pressure distribution would be to wear a left hand glove that only had the last three "fingers" (just cut off the top two, the palm part stays the same) and wear a right handed glove that had only the two middle fingers . This would force you to feel the club through the fingers you want to control the club.

Would this be legal?

Answer (score 4):

This is not permitted, under [Rule 14-3](http://www.randa.org/Rules-of-Golf/Appendices/Appendix-IV-DEVICES-AND-OTHER-EQUIPMENT/2-Gloves).

The rule states that a glove must "consist of a fitted covering of the hand with a separate sheath or opening for each digit (fingers and thumb)", and also must not have "features, other than visual aids, designed to assist the player in placing his hands in a consistent and/or specific position on the grip".

Comment: Aw shucks, thought I could get away with this !

Comment: Afraid not. Could you [accept the answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) please?

Comment: As an alternative, because the glove allows a sheath *or opening* for each finger, you can wear an open-fingered glove, but this isn't what Hogan is advocating.

Comment: I don't see how cutting off fingers would "assist the player in placing his hands in a consistent and/or specific position on the grip".